# HIFI amplifier: diagnosing power amplifier stage

Tags: amplifier

I have a Sony HCD-MD373 HIFI which experiences odd issues:

- there is no sound on attached HIFI speakers
- there is sound on headphones plugged into the headphone jack
- there **is** sound on headphones attached to the HIFI speaker connections

Signal path [click to zoom] (see top right hand corner):
[image]

The above descibed phenomena lets me conclude:

- the speaker output relay is working correctly
- mute control is working correctly

To me this leaves the following options:

- amplifier is defective
- overload detection is defective
- "DBFB DET" is defective (I believe that is some kind of bass feedback loop)

Amplifier board circuit [click to zoom]:
[image]

The amplifier fuses in the above board are ok.

Questions:

- Can anybody take an educated guess what the issue is likely to be?
- Any hints on how to proceed diagnosing this with only a multimeter?
- Can the [Sanyo STK4132MK2](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/41587/SANYO/STK4132.html) power amplifier IC be defective given that it is still able to drive headphones?
- Can the power supply to the power amplifier IC be defective given that the amplifier still drives headphones?

Comment: How have you ruled out the speakers themselves being defective?

Comment: @brhans By checking against known to be working speakers.

Comment: What is the impedance of the speakers?